# How to use pyside2 from the Ubuntu repository to develop programs?

Tags: 20.04, python3, pyside

When I run `apt search pyside` packages I get for example:

```
python3-pyside2.qtwidgets/focal 5.15.2-1+20.04+focal+release+build1 amd64
```

When I install it, how can I use it with my python-programm? Do I need to package my python-programm as .deb? How does it work and what do I need to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Installing `python3-pyside2.qtwidgets` alone may not be enough. Install all the following packages instead.

```
sudo apt install python3-pyside2.qtcore python3-pyside2.qtgui python3-pyside2.qtwidgets python3-pyside2.qtnetwork
```

> When I install it, how can I use it with my python-programm?

You just need to import appropriate libraries.
Example:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
```

> Do I need to package my python-programm as .deb?

If you want to use it yourself, then no.

If you want to distribute it, then you can either upload to PyPI and ask people to install from pip, or package it as .deb and distribute (alternatively, if the program is simple enough, just distribute the source, and ask users to install PySide2 manually).

Comment: Okay I will go ahead and give it a try(I think there is something wrong with my installation). Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @123 Check the updated answer.

Comment: I go ahead and check it as answered, when I get it running. If I shouldn't get it running I will come back and ask again.